# How can I use the Sci-kit learn pipeline to have variable inputs to an SVM?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, pipeline

I am currently using the pipeline class for some machine learning work. I'm looking at a linear and gaussian classifier. My code for the linear one is fine.

```
lsvm_w2v = Pipeline([
("word2vec vectorizer", MeanEmbeddingVectorizer(model)),
("SVM", svm.SVC(kernel='linear'))])
```

However, when looking at the gaussian estimator, I need to feed in a gamma value which is based on my training data "X", after the previous stage of the pipeline. Is this possible?

```
svm_w2v = Pipeline([
("word2vec vectorizer", MeanEmbeddingVectorizer(model)),
("SVM", svm.SVC(kernel='rbf',gamma=someFunction(X)))])
```

Comment: No, you cannot initialize the estimator again when inside a pipeline. What you can do is (if you want to calculate gamma based on previous step's output), you can make a wrapper over `SVC` and change the fit() method to accomodate that change.

Comment: Ahh, good suggestion! Thank you.